# How to determine why a word was included in description from vision api

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I used the computer vision api on an image. The word pizza was returned in describing the image and the only connection to pizza I can make is a pizza company logo on a napkin. The word birthday was also returned. Is there any way to figure out if the word pizza was returned because of the company logo, or it was a guess associated with the word birthday?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how much details the API gives you back. If it allows you to observe the intermediate outputs of the classifier that is used to categorize the image, you can see which parts of the image that results in high output values. The pizza company logo on a napkin, depending on how large it appears, is quite likely to cause this.

If you are using a more open API and a classifer, like keras and the networks provided under keras.applications, you can use what are called "class activation maps" to see which parts of the image causes the result.

If you find the above too had to do, one easy way to investigate the reason is to crop parts of the image using a loop and pass them to the API. I suspect that "birthday" might be related to a distributed feature and you might not be able to find where that comes from, whereas pizza might be from the logo or some other part of the image.